# How to respond to applicationWillResignActive differently from different View Controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios

When my application is interrupted, such as receiving a phone call, screen locked, or switching applications, I need it to respond differently depending on which view/viewcontroller is on screen at the time of the interruption.

in my first view controller, we'll call it VCA, I have this

```
              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(doSomething)
 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
 object:NULL];

    -(void)doSomething{
    //code here
    };
```

In VCB I have

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(doSomethingElse)
 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
 object:NULL];

    -(void)doSomethingElse{ //code here };
```

but if VCB is on screen, or any subsequent view controller (vcc, vcd, vce), and the screen is locked, it will only respond to the doSomething method defined in VCA. Even if I don't have the UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification in one of the view controllers that comes after VCA, it will still respond to the doSomethign method defined in VCA.

Is there any way I can make my application respond differently depending on which view is on screen when it goes into the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in **applicationDidEnterBackground**

```
if ([navigationViewController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[YourClass class]]) {
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying your doSomethingElse function is never called? Are you sure of this, maybe it is getting called in addition to doSomething? I think so.

In which case in doSomething and doSomethingElse you could add a check as the first line to ignore the notification if not currently loaded:

```
if ([self isLoaded] == NO)
   return;
```

Comment: I put NSLog in both doSomething and doSomethingElse and it appears that it's calling both. I tried your code but isLoaded doesn't appear to work.

Comment: this problem only raised when I decided to switch to a navigation controller in order to use custom segues. when i just used normal modal segues...each view controller would call its own selector for the notification. is there a way to do custom segues without a navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

How about you check the current visibleViewController when you received the notification? If it matches with your receiver than perform the action(s), otherwise ignore it.